# How do I conditionally create an array of class parameters from an array in D?

Tags: d

Say I have an associative array that contains a bunch of class instances. I want to find an idiomatic D way of creating an array (or range) containing properties that belong to class instances in the array that mean some boolean criteria.

See the example below, in this case I would want to create an array or range containing the age of students that are in the fifth grade.

I know how to do this with loops and conditionals, but if there is a built-in function or idiomatic way of doing this in D, that would be super helpful.

```
import std.stdio;

class Student {
    private:
        uint grade;
        uint age;
        uint year;

    public:
        this(uint g, uint a, uint y) {
            grade = g;
            age = a;
            year = y;
        }

        uint getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        uint getGrade() {
            return grade;
        }

        uint getYear() {
            return year;
        }
}

void main() {
    Student[uint] classroom;

    Student s1 = new Student(1, 5, 2);
    Student s2 = new Student(2, 6, 1);
    Student s3 = new Student(3, 7, 2);
    Student s4 = new Student(4, 8, 9);

    classroom[1] = s1;
    classroom[2] = s1;
    classroom[3] = s1;
    classroom[4] = s1;

    // I want to generate an array or range here containing the age of students who are in the X'th grade
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is little bit of functional programming with the help of the std.algorithm module:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm, std.array;


class Student {
    private:
        uint grade;
        uint age;
        uint year;

    public:
        this(uint g, uint a, uint y) {
            grade = g;
            age = a;
            year = y;
        }

        uint getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        uint getGrade() {
            return grade;
        }

        uint getYear() {
            return year;
        }
}

void main() {
    Student[uint] classroom;

    Student s1 = new Student(1, 5, 2);
    Student s2 = new Student(2, 6, 1);
    Student s3 = new Student(3, 7, 2);
    Student s4 = new Student(4, 8, 9);

    classroom[1] = s1;
    classroom[2] = s2;
    classroom[3] = s3;
    classroom[4] = s4;
    classroom[5] = new Student(3, 8, 3);

    // I want to generate an array or range here containing the age of students who are in the X'th grade
    uint grd = 3;

    auto ages = classroom.values
        .filter!(student => student.getGrade() == grd)
        .map!(student => student.getAge());
    writeln(ages);

    uint[] arr = ages.array;  // if you need to turn the range into an array
    writeln(arr);             // prints the same as above
}
```

Answer (score 2):

std.algorithm has your back:

```
import std.algorithm, std.array;
auto kids = classroom.values
    .filter!(student => student.grade == 5)
    .array;
```

If you want to do this for every grade at once, you need to sort and then chunkBy, something like:

```
classroom.values
    .sort!((x, y) => x.grade < y.grade)
    .chunkBy((x, y) => x.grade == y.grade)
```

Which gives you a range of [ranges of students with the same grade].

Comment: Thanks for this, but both of these examples return a range of students. Instead of a range of students, I want a range of properties belonging to those students, for instance a range of those student’s ages.